# Rails adds DEFAULT NULL to text column when using change_column

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration

I try to change the `AS` part of a column by using this migration:

```
as = %|JSON_EXTRACT(variants.properties, "$[*].key")|
change_column :variants, :properties_search, :text, as: as, stored: true
```

Which results in an SQL command that throws an error:

```
-- change_column(:variants, :properties_search, :text, {:as=>"JSON_EXTRACT(variants.properties, \"$[*].key\")", :stored=>true})
D, [2021-01-15T13:31:09.352362 #10763] DEBUG -- :    (0.7ms)  ALTER TABLE `variants` CHANGE `properties_search` `properties_search` text AS (JSON_EXTRACT(variants.properties, "$[*].key")) STORED DEFAULT NULL

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DEFAULT NULL' at line 1:
ALTER TABLE `variants` CHANGE `properties_search` `properties_search` text AS (JSON_EXTRACT(variants.properties, "$[*].key")) STORED DEFAULT NULL
```

In MySQL a column of type `text` can't have a default value, see
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html

> The BLOB, TEXT, GEOMETRY, and JSON data types cannot be assigned a default value.

When I remove the last part `DEFAULT NULL` and trigger the SQL by hand, it works.

So I'm wondering, how I can prevent Rails from adding this default value to the migration? I tried it by setting `default: nil` but this results in the same SQL call.

Comment: you could add `null: true` to the migration, or add another line `change_column_null :true`

Comment: this still results in the same SQL error